# shared_ptr - why does it break?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

While developing a tree-like data structure, I wrote something like this:

```
    #include <memory>

    class Node: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> {
    public:

        void set_root(Node & n);
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Node> root;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> leaf;
    };

    void Node::set_root(Node & n) {
        root = n.shared_from_this();
        n.leaf = shared_from_this();
    }

    int main() {
        Node n1, n2;
        n1.set_root(n2);
    }
```

The code compiles with **clang** but breaks run-time **("libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::bad_weak_ptr: bad_weak_ptr")** Why?

**EDIT**
So based on the answers, I came up with the version that seems to be working:

```
    #include <memory>

    class Node;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> Node_SP;

    class Node: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> {
    public:

        void set_root(Node & n);
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Node> root;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> leaf;
    };

    void Node::set_root(Node & n) {
        root = n.shared_from_this();
        n.leaf = shared_from_this();
    }

    int main() {
        Node_SP n1 = std::shared_ptr<Node>(new Node);
        Node_SP n2 = std::shared_ptr<Node>(new Node);

        n1->set_root(*n2);
    }
```

Comment: Not very important, but you might want to look into `boost::intrusive_ptr` instead.

Comment: You should use `std::make_shared<Node>()` instead of `std::shared_ptr<Node>(new Node);`, it's safer and faster and has more unicorns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shared_ptr` assumes the object is allocated on the heap, but you've allocated it on the stack.

Use `new` instead and let `shared_ptr` call `delete` for you.

Comment: Additionally, there needs to be at least one existing `shared_ptr` for the object

Comment: @user1520427: Yeah, that's a corollary of "let `shared_ptr` call `delete` for you". There would be no way for `shared_ptr` to call `delete` if it doesn't even own the object in the first place.

Comment: But there's ambiguity in that. Without knowing that an existing `shared_ptr` is necessary, you could be forgiven for thinking that you were referring to the one returned by `shared_from_this` and simply allocating an object on the heap was sufficient.

Comment: @user1520427: Ohh! I didn't understand what you meant. Yes, that's correct, I neglected to mention that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8):

To do it's job, `enable_shared_from_this<Node>` has to store a `weak_ptr<Node>` to itself. This `weak_ptr` is default-constructed to be null. When a `shared_ptr` is constructed to take over ownership of an object, either vía `make_shared` or by passing a raw pointer, it sets said `weak_ptr` to refer to that new `shared_ptr`. If you then call `shared_from_this()` on the object, the `weak_ptr` gets `lock`ed and another `shared_ptr` can be returned.

However, in your case there is no `shared_ptr` holding `n1` and `n2`, so when calling `shared_from_this()` the `lock` gets executed on the null `weak_ptr`, resulting in said exception.

**Long story short**: don't call `shared_from_this()` on a object that is not owned by a `shared_ptr` - especially not on stack based objects like in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to calling shared_from_this on an object t, there must be a std::shared_ptr that owns t.